# shift count >= width of type and macros vs inline function

Tags: c++, macros, inline

I'm working on some bit manipulation and run into weird different outputs of the same line of code putting in a macro vs in an inline function. The function returns the 64-bit mask that has `L` active bits from `N`-th position: `(~0<<N) - (~0<<(N+L))`. Could someone please tell me the reason why the outputs are different?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

#define ONES (~0UL)

#define MASK(from_bit, nbits) \
  (ONES << (from_bit)) - (ONES << ((from_bit) + (nbits)))

inline unsigned long int mask(size_t from_bit, size_t nbits) {
  return (ONES << from_bit) - (ONES << (from_bit + nbits));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  cout << "using #define:         " << bitset<64>(MASK(63, 3)) << endl;
  cout << "using inline function: " << bitset<64>(mask(63, 3)) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ -o test main.cc
main.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cc:15: warning: left shift count >= width of type
$ ./test
using #define:         1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
using inline function: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100
                                                                              ------^
```

Compiling with `-O3` option:

```
$ g++ -O3 -o test2 main2.cc
main.cc: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cc:15: warning: left shift count >= width of type
$ ./test2
using #define:         1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
using inline function: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                 ------^
```

Compiler information:

```
$ g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
```

Comment: Likely because you're shifting an (at most) 64 bit type by more than 64 bits, resulting in undefined behaviour. Pay attention to your compiler warnings!

Comment: So overflow left shifting doesn't drop the bits automatically as I thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not ignore the compiler warning. It tells you there's a problem.

You can legally only shift by fewer positions than there are bits in an integer type.

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

#define ONES (~0ULL)

#define MASK(from_bit, nbits) \
  (ONES << (from_bit)) - (ONES << (from_bit) << (nbits))

inline unsigned long long mask(unsigned from_bit, unsigned nbits) {
  return (ONES << from_bit) - (ONES << from_bit << nbits);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  cout << "using #define:         " << bitset<64>(MASK(63, 3)) << endl;
  cout << "using inline function: " << bitset<64>(mask(63, 3)) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/zulN9t)):

```
using #define:         1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
using inline function: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: thanks, nice trick for the `ONES << from_bit << nbits` part. I don't even have to use `ULL` for the mask.

Comment: I changed `UL` to `ULL` and `unsigned long` to `unsigned long long` to ensure there are 64 bits in the type. `unsigned long` is at least 32 bits, that is, it can be shorter than 64. `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be 64 bits or larger. Also, shift counts are small, no need to use anything potentially larger than `unsigned int` for them (e.g. `long` or `size_t`).

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler warning says it.

Your shifting amount (`from_bit + nbits`) is more than the size of the type you are using.

And the difference between macro and function is that, the former has no type check.